# How can we use gnosis protocol kit to fresh depoly and upgrade smart contracts

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk, safe-core

I was using gnosis protocol kit and api-kit to interact my gnosis safe with smart contract but now i have to deploy and upgrade my smart contract using  my gnosis safe account so, how can i do that.
So, please help me with this query.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new Safe with the Safe{Core} SDK you can follow this guide in the docs: https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/protocol-kit#deploy-a-safe

Currently the SDK does not allow to update a Safe to a newer version number of the contracts, but it can be done via the web interface